# Exposing Tomcat log files

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

Tomcat log location is :

```
/apache/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/logs
```

What is standard method of enabling access to these logs via browser ?

Is enabling Tomcat dir listing standard for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen similar setup done for one of the apps where I worked for an Australian telco whereby application logs are logged to a directory where Apache can serve them.

The pro is that it is really simple, just install Apache and most application developers are happy to download log files from their browser.

Just make sure the public does not access this directory.

The con being, if the log files are somewhat large that may take up quite a bit of bandwidth from your users.